# Searching a LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am making a simple prototype project using Java S2SE.  The goal is to make a text file, read it line by line, populate a linked list, then ask the user to enter first name and second name.

The format of text file is:

> firstnamesecondname mobile home mobile2 office
>
> contact1contact2 mobiles homes mobile2s offices

I concatenate the first name and second name in the text file.

I then ask the user to enter first and second name, and using concatenation of these two strings, will search the populated linked list. Wherever the node containing the string having these first name and second name occurs, split that node and display the result of that node

My code is:

```
try {
    String fullname;
    String mobile;
    String home;
    String mobile2;
    String office;

    Node current=first;

    while(current.data == null ? key !=null : !current.data.equals(key)) {
        String splitter[]=current.next.data.split(" ");

        //fullname=splitter[9];
        mobile=splitter[1];
        home=splitter[2];
        mobile2=splitter[3];
        office=splitter[4];

        if(current.next.data.split(" ")==null?key==null:){

            mobilefield.setText(mobile);
            homefield.setText(home);
            mobilefield2.setText(mobile2);
            officefield.setText(office);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("SORRY RECORD NOT LISTED IN DATABASE");
        }
            break;
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage()
        +"\nPLEASE TRY AGAIN !","Search Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

The problem is that all is going fine, but the search goes wrong for the first and up to the n-1th node in the list, but the last node isn't being reached in this search.

Comment: Why don't you use a standard java.util.List?

Comment: Solution to this problem actually makes a picture of hashing in front of me instead of linklist. You actually store keys in a table and link the actual data to the keys...thats hashing

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, you're attempting to reference a `next` node that's potentially null.

`current.next.data` could be `null`, and if that's the case, then you'll get an NPE.

Your loop should focus on the *ith* piece that it's working on - that is to say, of a linked list of size *n*, when I get a node *i* of *n*, then I should do **this**.

Also, you shouldn't be working in a node that has no data in it.  Skip over the ones that are empty.

```
while(current.data != null)
```

Finally, advance your `current` reference or you'll loop indefinitely.

```
current = current.next;
```

One other observation:

- While editing, I didn't know from context if both of those lines should be on the same line.  If that's the case, then you would want to use constants in place of raw integers to indicate what goes where - for example, the name you're looking for would be in `[0]` and could be called `FULL_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered from your question, I have modified your code. This should hopefully work:

```
try {
String fullname;
String mobile;
String home;
String mobile2;
String office;

Node current;

    //This loop will start from the first `Node`, check for `null`, then check if it is equal to the `key`. If not, then it will advance to `next`
for(current=first; current!=null && !current.data.equals(key); current = current.next);

    //the loop will terminate if current is null or is equal to key. If it is equal to key, we should display data.
if(current.data.equals(key))
{

    String splitter[]= current.data.split(" ");

    fullname=splitter[0];
    mobile=splitter[1];
    home=splitter[2];
    mobile2=splitter[3];
    office=splitter[4]; 

    mobilefield.setText(mobile);
    homefield.setText(home);
    mobilefield2.setText(mobile2);
    officefield.setText(office);
}
else
    throw new FileNotFoundException("SORRY RECORD NOT LISTED IN DATABASE");

} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage()
    +"\nPLEASE TRY AGAIN !","Search Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

**EDIT:** Added comments.

Comment: Divyanshu thanks for your help but now it gives nullpointer exception can u plz help me at juni1289@hotmail.com pleaseeeeee actually i have a project so i need help

Comment: it only searches the last node of the list :(

Comment: @user1930526:  All we can do is provide hints. We're not here to help you do your homework.  Feel free to ask for clarification on a particular answer, but don't give out your personal e-mail address looking for help.

Comment: @makoto m not asking u for to do my homework lols and i just want to search a desired node containing data like fnamelname mobile home bla bla then i want to split it and show it searching a node from a list of nodes!

Comment: @user1930526: If you have a problem tell all of us about it here. So that someone will help you out *here*. It not only helps you to get the problem solved, but also helps others who might be searching for a similar type of problem.

Comment: Sir I actually i want to search any Node from the list containing type of data i.e. firstnamelastname mobile home i mean to say that the Node has data with spaces and i want to search that type of data containing spaces so help me out in doing so pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee I beg YOU !!!